# How use cakebox with HTTPS

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I just install and set cakebox to my server but it doesn't work. 
After some research I found it doesn't work with SSL, and I already set apache to using SSL and redirect http to https. 
So I try without ssl and it works, problem is I don't want to remove entierly SSL from apache just for cakebox.

So how can I do to use cakebox without remove SSL and https from apache ?

Thank you.